# Why is there no autocompletion for block arguments?

Tags: xcode, swift, autocomplete

When I type in a block that has some arguments, I'm not getting autocompletion for those arguments. Other variables will autocomplete just fine, but the arguments for the block will not.

I don't know enough about blocks in Swift to know if this is intentional, but whenever I type something that doesn't autocomplete, I feel like something's wrong.

Here's an example. When I go to type 'action', I begin typing "act...", but Xcode will not finish the word 'action'. Everything else will autocomplete, but not the word 'action'.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        // Typing 'action' in here will not autocomplete
    }))

alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
        // Typing 'textField' in here will not autocomplete
        textField.textAlignment = .Center
    })
```

I'm using Xcode 7.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the state of Xcode. Swift is a brand new language and the tools supporting it are still very limited.

You can try filing a bug report with Apple via radar.apple.com, but you'll probably get a response along the lines of "Your bug has been closed because it is a duplicate of ...", meaning Apple is aware of the problem and will (hopefully) fix it in a future release.

Comment: Well, it's good to know that I wasn't doing something wrong. I was wondering if it was "just me" or if others had the same problem. I guess I'll just have to deal with this small annoyance like everyone else until it's fixed.